# Error de conversión desde Java: none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: kotlin, junit

tras convertir mi código de Java a Kotlin desde la página de [Try Kotlin](https://try.kotlinlang.org), me sale el siguiente error:

> error: none of the following functions can be called with the
>   arguments supplied:  public open fun assertEquals(p0: Double, p1:
>   Double, p2: Double): Unit defined in org.junit.Assert public open fun
>   assertEquals(p0: Float, p1: Float, p2: Float): Unit defined in
>   org.junit.Assert public open fun assertEquals(p0: String!, p1: Any!,
>   p2: Any!): Unit defined in org.junit.Assert @Deprecated public open
>   fun assertEquals(p0: String!, p1: Array<(out) Any!>!, p2: Array<(out)
>   Any!>!): Unit defined in org.junit.Assert @Deprecated public open fun
>   assertEquals(p0: String!, p1: Double, p2: Double): Unit defined in
>   org.junit.Assert public open fun assertEquals(p0: String!, p1: Long,
>   p2: Long): Unit defined in org.junit.Assert
>       assertEquals(7, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("007"), 1e-9)
>       ^

Código convertido:

```
package com.codewars.geoffp
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert.*

class UnwantedDollarsTest {
  @Test
  fun moneyValue() {
    assertEquals(12.34, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("12.34"), 1e-9)
    assertEquals(5.67, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue(" $5.67"), 1e-9)
    assertEquals(-0.89, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("-0.89"), 1e-9)
    assertEquals(-0.10, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("-$ 0.1"), 1e-9)
    assertEquals(-2.3456, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("$-2.3456"), 1e-9)
    assertEquals(7, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("007"), 1e-9)
    assertEquals(89.0, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue(" $ 89"), 1e-9)
    assertEquals(0.11, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue(" .11"), 1e-9)
    assertEquals(0.20, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("$.2"), 1e-9)
    assertEquals(-0.34, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("-.34"), 1e-9)
    assertEquals(0.0, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("$$$"), 1e-9)
  }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

El error es muy sutil,

Java realiza internamente el casting de int a double, pero al parecer Kotlin no, es por ello que se debe corregir

```
assertEquals(7, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("007"), 1e-9)
```

que es la línea que causa el error.

Mientras que la versión web no es capaz de hacer correctamente la conversión, ésta se realiza correctamente en el IDE.

```
package com.codewars.geoffp
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert.*

class UnwantedDollarsTest {
  @Test
    fun moneyValue() {
        assertEquals(12.34, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("12.34"), 1e-9)
        assertEquals(5.67, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue(" $5.67"), 1e-9)
        assertEquals(-0.89, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("-0.89"), 1e-9)
        assertEquals(-0.10, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("-$ 0.1"), 1e-9)
        assertEquals(-2.3456, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("$-2.3456"), 1e-9)
        assertEquals(7.0, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("007"), 1e-9)
        assertEquals(89.0, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue(" $ 89"), 1e-9)
        assertEquals(0.11, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("   .11"), 1e-9)
        assertEquals(0.20, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("$.2"), 1e-9)
        assertEquals(-0.34, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("-.34"), 1e-9)
        assertEquals(0.0, UnwantedDollars.moneyValue("$$$"), 1e-9)

    }
}
```